# .onChange shows previous change instead of present and fires only after second trigger

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, state

I'm new to Swift and can't understand what's wrong with my code:

```
@State var selectedCourse: String = "1"
@State var napravlenie: [String] = [""]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Text("Выберите вашу группу")
                    .padding(.bottom,80)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold))

                Text("Курс")
                    .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(width: 370,alignment: .leading)
                    //.padding()
                
                Menu {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedCourse, label: EmptyView()) {
                        ForEach(course, id: \.self) {option in
                            Text (option)
                                .tag (1)
                        }
                    }
                    
                } label: {
                    customLabel_1
                    
                } .onChange(of: selectedCourse) { newValue in
                    napravlenie = viewModel.readValue(kyrs: newValue)
                }
                
                Text("Направление")
                    .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(width: 370,alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.bottom,28)
                
                Menu {
                        
                        Picker(selection: $selectedNapravlenie, label: EmptyView()) {
                            ForEach(napravlenie, id: \.self) {option in
                                Text (option)
                                    .tag (2)
                            }
                        }
                    } label: {
                    customLabel_2
                    }

               }
        }
```

the thing is that I want to update **napravlenie** array each time the first Picker is used and than pass that array as a **ForEach** of the second Picker, but it only updates after second trigger and shows an array that was triggered in the first time. I want the second Picker to update immediately, what should I do?

here's my viewModel code

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseDatabase


class userViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var key = ""
    @Published var moreKey = []
    @Published var key2 = ""
    @Published var moreKey2 = []
    @Published var nameKey2 = ""
    @Published var nameKey3 = ""
    //@Published var nameMoreKey = []
    @Published var object: String? = nil
    @Published var userName: Any? = []
    
    var ref = Database.database().reference()
    
    // функция которая находит институты, из фб по выбору курса
    
    
    func readValue(kyrs:String) -> [String]{
        
        ref.child("Курс - " + kyrs).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children{                                 //тут он проверяет типо каждый раз нужный курс
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                self.key = snap.key                                         //все что тут находится я хз
                self.moreKey.append(self.key)
                print(self.moreKey)
            }
            
        }
        let newArray: [String] = self.moreKey.compactMap { String(describing: $0) }
        self.moreKey.removeAll()
        return newArray
    }
```

For example, when i choose anything in first Picker, the second one doesn't update **napravlenie** array, but after second trigger, the second picker shows array, that should've been presented after first trigger

Comment: BTW those variables are State 
'@State var selectedCourse: String = "1"'
'@State var napravlenie: [String] = [""]'
the second array is filled in fuction

Comment: Please add your `viewModel` code. In general providing a [mre] will help other people understand and solve your issue. Reading [ask] may also help you improve your question.

Comment: done! almost forgot about it

Comment: You are in an async context here. You are manipulating `moreKey` inside the return closure of your FireBase method. But you are returning imediatly after calling it without waiting for the result. So the values return base on the state before the FireBase closure returns.

Comment: Probably best reading up on Swift concurency. Especially for FireBase and use an appropriate pattern.

Comment: thx mate, are there any guides for my particular situation? cant really find one

Comment: Note, you should not be using `.tag (1)` and `.tag (2)` in your `Pickers`, the tag should be a `String` and not the same value for each loop of the `ForEach`, for example, something like `.tag (option)`.

Comment: The FireBase documentation should be a good starting point. Next would be a search with your favorite search engine on "Swift concurrency". There are a lot of tutorials out there.

Comment: +1 to @burnsi's comment. observeSingleEvent:withBlock is asynchronous and will, most likely, happen after readValue(kyrs:) returns. Hence, it would return values previously stored in moreKey, which appears to be what you are getting.

Comment: As for how to resolve the issue, the fundamental problem there is the asynchronous nature of the Firebase query – which, to be fair, allows the app to be responsive. However, it means that you would need some asynchronous code to update the view as well. As a "quick and dirty" solution, I would either take advantage of the ObservableObject nature of the model or use a Binding. Be mindful, however, that observeSingleEvent(of:withBlock:) might be calling the block on a background thread (couldn't find relevant docs about it).